# Automate login to DEFRA eDomero website - VBA

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vba

I'm trying to automate access to the website

https://secure.edomero.defra.gov.uk/Default.aspx?Menu=Menu&Module=SecureHome

But it's not working quite the way I would expect. The user credentials I have are fine (I can log in manually) but when I enter them using the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
IEexp.Visible = True
IEexp.Navigate ("https://signon.defra.gov.uk/Default.aspx")
Do While IEexp.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Dim inputElement As HTMLInputElement
Set inputElement = IEexp.Document.getElementById("myHolder_Step2_txtUserName")
inputElement.Value = "Username"

Set inputElement = IEexp.Document.getElementById("myHolder_Step2_txtPassword")
inputElement.Value = "Password"

IEexp.Document.getElementById("myHolder_Navigation_btnNext").Click


Set IExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

It seems that the "Next" button isn't submitting the variables properly using the code, as it throws up an error message asking me to fill in one of the three check boxes in the middle of the screen - my guess is that the field data isn't being passed along properly? If I click the button manually it works fine. The code behind the button is:

```
<input name="ctl00$myHolder$Navigation$btnNext" class="NextButton" id="myHolder_Navigation_btnNext" style="color: white; cursor: hand;" onmouseover="goLiteNext(this.id);" onmouseout="goDimNext(this.id);" onclick='ClickHandler();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$myHolder$Navigation$btnNext", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="submit" value="      Next">
```

Any thoughts about how I can proceed?

Comment: I wasn't able to load the page at all with the direct link in your code. But this code netted a similar result: https://pastebin.com/kMVFfFGw where it was giving me the same error - asking for an option from the middle radio buttons but also saying the password was incorrect. Obviously I cannot test further without the correct credentials.

Comment: Does it give the same error with a valid username and password?

Comment: It does. The error message about the username and password goes away, but the error message next to the check boxes stays there.

If I manually fill the data and use VBA to just click the button, it's fine. If I auto-fill the data but then manually click the button, it's fine. It's just doing all of it automatically that goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further. I tried using sendkeys to manually get to the button, but obviously I run into the same error for the password. If you want to try it just for trouble shooting - here was the code I tried. https://pastebin.com/B8DuWcDt Good luck!